# phpmyadmin: #1055 - 'information_schema.s.SCHEMA_NAME' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I am getting the following error in PHPMyAdmin when I attempt to do click "Databases" tab:

> #1055 - 'information_schema.s.SCHEMA_NAME' isn't in GROUP BY

Please advise on what code in phpmyadmin file needs to be updated to fix this query and how to re-write it...
Seems to be a bug in PHPMyAdmin, but I don't wanna wait around until they fix in a "later" release.

Comment: I found this with a quick search in google, this might solve your issue. http://mgelbana.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/mysql-error-code-1055-yourschema-yourtable-yourcolumn-isnt-in-group-by-error/

Comment: in MySQL 5.7 sql mode is set by default to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL : isn't in GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by)