# MySQL : isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1055

The site produces results, but with SELECT COUNT and SELECT query with GROUP BY having two different result counts. This is likely due to the error that is displaying in phpmyadmin but not on the site.

**The Queries:**

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `name`) as `numrows` FROM `users` WHERE `verified` = '1'

SELECT `name`, `type`, `language`, `code` FROM `users` WHERE `verified` = '1' GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

PhpMyAdmin provides the following error:

> 1055 - 'main.users.type' isn't in GROUP BY

When reading MySQL docs, I'm still unclear what it is I have to fix. I can't seem to grasp this.

Comment: The first query is doing an implicit grouping by name.  The second, wrote a similar way would be something like:

SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `verified` = '1' GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: I'm not sure what you're implying.

With the query:

SELECT name,type,language FROM synset WHERE verified = '1' GROUP BY name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 0, 25

The same error would occur. type isn't in Group By

If I add type and language, the error disappears. Is this due to an upgrade to MySql maybe?

SELECT name,type,language FROM synset WHERE verified = '1' GROUP BY name,type,language ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 0, 25 

will work fine.

Comment: terrible query time when adding all fields to the group by, obviously

Comment: Hi @James - any columns/expressions used in either the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses must be contained in the GROUP BY clause if they are not being aggregated (COUNT, SUM, etc).  That is why you were getting the error - you were selecting the columns type, language, and code but they were not in the GROUP BY clause (as the accepted answer shows).  If there is a setting in MySQL to automatically group, I would be extremely cautious of using that personally.

Comment: @JordanParker: "*If there is a setting in MySQL to automatically group*" - that is actually the default behaviour. James apparently enabled the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option. Otherwise the statement would have just returned "random" results (MySQL doesn't call it random, they call it "indeterminate") http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wow I had no idea about how deep this goes with 92 vs 99 SQL standard - thanks for the info!
http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: If there are two users with the same `name` but different `type`, `language` or `code`, what values do you expect to get for these columns? The query is invalid.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to have a full group by:

```
SELECT `name`, `type`, `language`, `code` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `verified` = '1' 
GROUP BY `name`, `type`, `language`, `code` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

SQL92 requires that all columns (except aggregates) in the select clause is part of the group by clause. SQL99 loosens this restriction a bit and states that all columns in the select clause must be functionally dependent of the group by clause. MySQL by default allows for partial group by and this may produce non-deterministic answers, example:

```
create table t (x int, y int);
insert into t (x,y) values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3);
select x,y from t group by x;
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

I.e. a random y is select for the group x. One can prevent this behavior by setting @@sql_mode:

```
set @@sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
select x,y from t group by x; 
ERROR 1055 (42000): 'test.t.y' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Comment: I was just reading the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY :) The problem with this group by requiring all columns, is the speed of the query. But - this is the correct answer. Can set the sql_mode, in my case I don't need to prevent the behavior. In other cases, this is good to know and good to follow.

Comment: Great answer, and great partial-group-by example helps a lot! Big thanks!

Comment: This is a dramatically different query to that of OP's. Adding all the columns is the nuclear option of resolving an ambiguous group by.

Comment: Not a "random" aggregate, an *appropriate* aggregate. @O. Jones has a good suggestion.

Comment: You aren't selecting rows, you are selecting aggregations of rows. That's what group by *means*

Answer (score 14):

The best solution to this problem is, of course, using a complete `GROUP BY` expression.

But there's another solution that works around the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` blocking of the old MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT name, 
       ANY_VALUE(type) type,
       ANY_VALUE(language) language,
       ANY_VALUE(code) code 
  FROM users  
 WHERE verified = '1' 
 GROUP BY name 
 ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

`ANY_VALUE()` explicitly declares what used to be implicit in MySQL's incomplete `GROUP BY` operations -- that the server can choose, well, any, value to return.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too! 
If someone wishes all the options to handle that error, here they are:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value

Comment: this works but only use when you really know that the ANY_VALUE column have same value so it can capture one easily and you get correct results when using with GROUP BY and you really know that only the GROUP BY column have to be specific.

Comment: This really helps more than every solution above. Where I'm on a shared hosting cPanel and there's no way to change the sql_mode, I've had to look for workarounds that don't mess up my queries. This way, you keep your query and simply add ```ANYVALUE(cellname) cellname``` and voila it works.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution mentioned multiple times above is to turn off that annoying ***'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'*** e.g. like in this post:
[Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by#36033983)

I think this solution is very useful if you do not want to refactor the whole project for multiple hours. And if you do not care about the unpredictable values of the columns which are not list of the ***GROUP BY***.

Comment: Disabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` forces MySQL to accept invalid SQL `GROUP BY` queries. As a consequence, the [values it returns for the columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause are indeterminate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). This means the query can and is allowed to return different results using the same input data.

Comment: @axiac Sure I've taken it into account, that the columns not mentioned in the GROP BY statement will return some unpredictable values. If I need e.g. the entries grouped by land mark and don't care about id's, than disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY might be most reasonable. E.g. if you have a legacy ORM which appends that id into SELECT automatically no matter if you want it.

So I would be glad, if leave my answer by 0.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to see why it is like that. Earlier versions allowed us to be negligent a bit: while the values of the grouped column are completely listed (one from each without exceptions) in the result, values of the other selected column(s) are more or less omitted - but the code can't (does not want to) tell which ones on your behalf:

```
- Hey, MYSQL, list the families of the street - but add a first name as well to every row.
- Okay sir, but shall I use the father's or the mother's or...? I'm a machine, give exact orders!
```

Now that we understand the why, we can decide if we have preferences regarding the other column(s). Use

```
MAX() AS
MIN() AS
etc, works with strings, too
```

or if it's really all the same, e.g. there's no difference between the nonaggregated values that are related to the grouped one, use

```
ANY_VALUE() AS
```

Either way, you let mysql know that you're aware of being "equivocal" but you really don't want to focus on all the columns other than the one(s) you grouped.

Answer (score -3):

Just disable strictness for the query.