# Sphinx - no delta:sql_range_query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sphinx

I've been trying to get the Sphinx Search plugin for WordPress working but have run into a head scratcher. I have Sphinx on the server and running fine with the test database install that comes with the source. However, when I try to index WP using the sphinx.conf provided by Sphinx Search plugin ([copy here](http://pastebin.com/1vpyagzS)) it refuses to process. When I run it by command line I get the following output:

```
# /usr/local/bin/indexer --rotate --config /home/example.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/sphinx.conf dk_delta dk_main dk_stats
Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/home/example.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'dk_delta'...
ERROR: index 'dk_delta': sql_range_query: 'example.com.p.post_title' isn't in GROUP BY (DSN=mysql://dekanta_flyus3r:***@localhost:3306/example.com).
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.003 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
indexing index 'dk_main'...
ERROR: index 'dk_main': sql_range_query: 'example.com.p.post_title' isn't in GROUP BY (DSN=mysql://dekanta_flyus3r:***@localhost:3306/example.com).
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.003 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
indexing index 'dk_stats'...
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.003 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
total 1 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 7 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.4 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=20768).
```

The problem is surely that there is no dk_delta, dk_main or dk_stats tables in the wordpress database (I'm using dk_ prefix) which is what has confused me as this plugin is compatible up to and including latest wordpress. This leads me to believe that I must be missing an important step in the process e.g do I have to index all the database first with sphinx, install extra sql tables etc.

I've posted on wordpress support forum for this plugin but no-one has replied and its a month since there was any activity there so not getting my hopes up. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you are using a recent version of MySQL, which has more strict semantics on `GROUP BY` queries. The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option has been turned on.

Those errors are produced by the MySQL server, `indexer` is just 'reporting' it was unable to run the MySQL queries provided in the config file.

http://www.tocker.ca/2014/01/24/proposal-to-enable-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-by-default.html

[MySQL : isn't in GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/02/12/why-i-use-only-full-group-by/

The queries in that config file are for a older version of MySQL, historically MySQL is very lenient how you write GROUP BY queries.

Either

1. the MySQL queries need updating to work with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled or
2. can change MySQL Server settings to allow these types of queries.

---

for 1. make liberal use of the `ANY_VALUE()` function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value

(**in fact the documentation for that function, is perhaps the most concise explanation of the problem!**)

Comment: That makes sense, I am using mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB on this box. I'll read through the docs you posted to see if I can get further with this, appreciate your help.

Comment: OK, you nailed it, for speed purposes so I can get this up and running I removed ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from sql_mode in the my.cnf, restarted and presto indexer works its magic as it should. Thanks again.