# Stored Procedure ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-by

I have the following problem in a stored procedure:

```
{"code":"ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP","errno":1055,"sqlState":"42000","index":0}
```

Initially I suspected that it was the passing of parameters that were wrong but when debugging my application I noticed that the parameters are correct, with this I do not know what may be happening, below is my Procedure code.
My Stored Procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS clusbe.proc_buscarMidias;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_buscarMidias`(IN `id_usuario` INT, IN `latitude` DOUBLE, IN `longitude` DOUBLE, IN `interesses` VARCHAR(255), IN `val_offset` INT)
BEGIN
    SET @id     = id_usuario;
    SET @offset = val_offset;
    SET @lat    = latitude;
    SET @long   = longitude;
    SET @int    = interesses;

    SET @sql = ("SELECT *  , SUM(peso) AS peso_total     FROM (
                        (SELECT p.id,
                                p.midia,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN func_distancia(?,?, e.latitude, e.longitude) < 100 THEN 15
                                    WHEN func_distancia(?,?, e.latitude, e.longitude) < 200 THEN 10
                                    WHEN func_distancia(?,?, e.latitude, e.longitude) < 500 THEN  5
                                    ELSE 0
                                END AS peso,
                               (SELECT group_concat(' ', i.interesse) FROM interesse AS i
                                LEFT JOIN post_interesse AS pi ON i.id = pi.interesse
                                WHERE pi.post = p.id) AS interesses

                        FROM post AS p
                        LEFT JOIN  post_interesse AS pi ON pi.post       = p.id
                        LEFT JOIN  interesse      AS i  ON pi.interesse  = i.id
                        INNER JOIN endereco    AS e  ON p.localizacao = e.id
                        INNER JOIN usuario     AS u  ON p.criador     = u.id
                        WHERE (FIND_IN_SET (i.interesse, ?) OR ? = '')
                        AND (p.tipo = '0' OR p.tipo= '1')
                        AND p.criador <> ?
                        AND p.criador NOT IN (SELECT usuario FROM usuario_bloqueado WHERE usuario_bloqueado = ?)
            AND (p.id NOT IN (SELECT post_ocultado FROM post_ocultado WHERE usuario = ? ) AND p.criador NOT IN (SELECT usuario_ocultado FROM post_ocultado WHERE usuario = ? ))
                        AND p.area_post = 'feed')

                UNION
                        (SELECT p.id,
                                p.midia,
                                COUNT(p.id) AS peso,
                               (SELECT group_concat(i.interesse) FROM interesse AS i
                                LEFT JOIN post_interesse AS pi ON i.id = pi.interesse
                                WHERE pi.post = p.id) AS interesses
                        FROM post AS p
                        LEFT JOIN  post_interesse AS pi ON pi.post       = p.id
                        LEFT JOIN  interesse      AS i  ON pi.interesse  = i.id
                        INNER JOIN endereco       AS e  ON p.localizacao = e.id
                        INNER JOIN usuario        AS u  ON p.criador     = u.id
                        WHERE (FIND_IN_SET (i.interesse, ?) OR ? = '')
                        AND (p.tipo = '0' OR p.tipo = '1')
                        AND p.criador <> ?
                        AND p.criador NOT IN (SELECT usuario FROM usuario_bloqueado WHERE usuario_bloqueado = ?)
            AND (p.id NOT IN (SELECT post_ocultado FROM post_ocultado WHERE usuario = ? ) AND p.criador NOT IN (SELECT usuario_ocultado FROM post_ocultado WHERE usuario = ? ))
                        AND p.area_post = 'feed'
                        GROUP BY p.id)
                ) AS tbl
        where tbl.peso > 0
                GROUP BY tbl.id
                ORDER BY peso_total DESC
                LIMIT 10
                OFFSET ?");

    PREPARE stmt_midias FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt_midias USING @lat, @long, @lat, @long, @lat, @long, @int, @int, @id, @id, @id, @id,
                              @int, @int, @id, @id, @id, @id, @offset;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_midias;
END;
```

I wonder if anyone knows how I can solve this or what may be happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL : isn't in GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by)

Comment: Check out your group by clauses, one of them violates the rules described in the duplicate topic.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from mysql console

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```