# get total count in each ids from different table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to get each id's total count from another table named assign job. i saved user data into my users table and i add 3 jobs into assign job table with user id.

but now i want to get total added jobs from assign job table where user ids in my users table at once.

I wrote this function

```
$assignjob = DB::table('users')
->join('assign_jobs', 'users.user_id', '=', 'assign_jobs.user_id')
->get()
->count();
```

but this shows me total count in my assign job table. but i want to get different count for each user ids.

i want to assign different color rows with this assign job total count values.

can any one help me.

**User Table:**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      user_id        |     name         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          123        |     john         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          234        |     peter        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**assign job table:**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      id             |     user_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     123          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     123          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |     234          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |     234          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` clause for your user's `id` column and add `COUNT()` to your select. Try:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->select('users.user_id', DB::raw('COUNT(assign_jobs.user_id) AS jobs_count'))
    ->join('assign_jobs', 'users.user_id', '=', 'assign_jobs.user_id')
    ->groupBy('users.user_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thank you. it works. how can i show different colors for this array counts in my view table

Comment: how to show other details like name, email in users table with this query

Comment: @KalanaMihiranga tweak `->select(...)` method. If you want to select all columns from `users` table then switch `'users.user_id'` to `'users.*'`. [Check out the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects) on query builder for more info.

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'jobnetuva.users.id' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: @Kalana are you sure we are talking about MySQL here? Because by default MySQL allows partial `group by` clauses for non-aggregated columns and should not produce any errors. [Check answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by). So to solve this restriction you will have to `groupBy(...)` all the columns you want to select from `users` (not just `user_id`).

Comment: yes sure i write this with Mysql. i tried different ways. but i can't find how to show all details

Comment: if these tables want to make relationships

Comment: if you wnat to select all columns. @KalanaMihiranga

`$query =  DB::table('users')
        ->join('assign_jobs', 'users.user_id', '=', 'assign_jobs.user_id')
        ->select('users.*, assign_jobs.*')
        ->groupBy('users.user_id','users.driver_name')
        ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(assign_jobs.user_id) AS shipments_count'),'name','anther_column')
        ->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct usesr ID to loop into it to have the count for each users

Answer (score 0):

try this:

add below relation to User Model:

```
public function assignJobs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AssignJob::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

and in controller:

```
User::withCount('assignJobs')->get();
```