# mysql query group by not working on mysql version 10.2.22 mariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, version

MySQL query not working on live server mysql version 10
MyCode:

```
SELECT *, MIN(tbl_room_inventory.rin_number_of_rooms) AS min_room, MAX(tbl_room_inventory.rin_temp_number_of_rooms) AS max_temp_room
FROM tbl_room_type,tbl_room_inventory
WHERE tbl_room_type.room_id=tbl_room_inventory.room_id AND
      tbl_room_type.room_status=1 AND
      tbl_room_inventory.rin_date BETWEEN 1551117600 AND 1551204000
GROUP BY tbl_room_type.room_id
HAVING MIN(tbl_room_inventory.rin_number_of_rooms)>0
ORDER BY tbl_room_type.room_tariff ASC
```

Same code working properly on the local server. But not working on the live server.

Here is the error of live server:
[image]

And here is the result of mysql 5 its working

[image]

Comment: Your current query makes no sense, and won't run on any database, in general.  Please include sample data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Possible duplicate, [Isn't in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by)

Comment: I edited and added the same query and showing the result of two servers. one of getting results other not.

Comment: @RaviGaudani its not duplicate question please check my full question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can try by disabling `only_full_group_by`

**set global**

```
sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: @Sabbir  try to disable "only_full_group_by" first by executing above query using PHPMyAdmin

Comment: I using this on php code 

`$sql = 'here is my sql query';
        
        $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql);`

Comment: Yes you can try as you shown : please follow : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: I execute on phpmyadmin and its works fine. But how to add this on php page using variables; N.B: I have using this on live server cpanel.

Comment: @Sabbir you can set this globally: try to search "Set only_full_group_by globally"

Comment: see the error on image https://ibb.co/tPRZ4DP  Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation