# Create variable based query to select data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I created a helper function for count all notification in navbar, For this I am storing clause in a single variable.

I am accessing it by calling-

```
countData("notification","WHERE seen_status = '0'")
```

My function is-

```
function countData($table,$clause) {
    $result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM $table $clause");
    return count($result);
}
```

It working fine, but getting error in-

```
countData("projects","GROUP BY user")
```

I can use groupBy('user') but problem is, I don't want to pass too many variable inside my function.
So, is there any option to run my custom query by using single variable?

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'invoicestatus.notification.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT * FROM notification GROUP BY user)

Comment: The reference you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by

Comment: Also note that when you group by, the actual id (pk) of the row in essence becomes irrelevant and meaningless.

Comment: This is wasteful because you should just be using the `COUNT()` function, dangerous because you aren't doing any escaping, and probably redundant because you should be able to use built-in functions to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> The `GROUP BY` statement is often used with aggregate functions (`COUNT()`, `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `SUM()`, `AVG()`) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

So the problem here is that you need to use an aggregate function first then group it

Comment: Your answer is correct 1+ vote. But SELECT * FROM notification GROUP BY user; working in phpmyadmin. I think this not works in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think your group by must have a specific column in your select.

try that

```
function countData($columns,$table,$clause) {
    $result = DB::select("SELECT $columns FROM $table $clause");
    return count($result);
}

countData("user","projects","GROUP BY user")
```

or you can simply make one variable for all your selects

```
function countData($query) { $result = DB::select($query); return count($result); }
```

Comment: Same error Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'invoicestatus.notification.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT id FROM notification GROUP BY user)

Comment: Column in your select must be on your group by (same columns for it to work bro)
I don't think Asterisk will work