# MySQL sorting and groupby

Tags: mysql

Is grouping possible after sorting in MySQL? I read some articles regarding this, but none of the implementations were able to give me the result that I want.

My current data structure (after multiple joins) is

[image]

What I am willing to achieve is to group the data by pid where the data is sorted in desc order as per the created_at date.

```
pid   id   ....
3     16   ....
4     8   ....
2     6   ....
1     5   ....
```

Any idea on how this can be acheived?

Comment: What is wrong with sorting after grouping, where it makes logical sense to do a sort on the smallest data set

Comment: I am guessing your are making use of the MySQL fault [This is not actually allowed in "proper SQL." You are only allowed to select columns that are part of the grouping, or the result of using aggregate functions. MySQL has a more fault-tolerant mode, in which it allows for this - but the values of all other columns, 
that are not part of the grouping, would be those of one "random" record inside 
the group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by)

Comment: I am guessing you want one of the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] solutions. This type of question is asked daily on Stack Overflow, and there are many solutions posted already.