# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'new.bank_accounts.id' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'new.bank_accounts.id' isn't in GROUP BY (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `bank_accounts`.`id`, `bank_accounts`.`holder_name`, `bank_accounts`.`bank_name`, sum(amount) as total from `revenues` left join `bank_accounts` on `revenues`.`account_id` = `bank_accounts`.`id` where `revenues`.`created_by` = 2 and `revenues`.`created_by` = 2 group by `revenues`.`account_id`)
```

The line of code `$reportData['revenueAccounts'] = $revenueAccounts->get();` is fetching revenue account data from the database and storing it in the `$reportData` variable. Here's how it works:

`$revenueAccounts` is an instance of the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder class`, which represents a query to the database.
The `get()` method on $revenueAccounts executes the query and returns a collection of records from the revenue_accounts table in the database.
The `$reportData` variable is an array that stores the data for the report. The line of code `$reportData['revenueAccounts'] = $revenueAccounts->get();` assigns the collection of revenue account records to the `$reportData['revenueAccounts']` key in the array.
Overall, this line of code fetches the revenue account data from the database and stores it in an array for use in generating a report.

```
$bankAccount = BankAccount::find($request->account);

$filter['account'] = !empty($bankAccount) ? $bankAccount->holder_name . ' - ' . $bankAccount->bank_name : '';

if ($bankAccount->holder_name == 'Cash') 
{
    $filter['account'] = 'Cash';
}

if ($request->type == 'revenue' || !isset($request->type)) 
{
    $reportData['revenues'] = $revenues->get();
    $revenueAccounts->where('revenues.created_by', '=', \Auth::user()->creatorId());
    $reportData['revenueAccounts'] = $revenueAccounts->get();
}

if ($request->type == 'payment') 
{
    $reportData['payments'] = $payments->get();
    $paymentAccounts->where('payments.created_by', '=', \Auth::user()->creatorId());
}
```

I'M having issue to find all problems

Comment: The columns you retrieve has to belong to columns grouped by. Reference more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by

Comment: Also this is clearly a problem with group by, feels like something is missing with no part of your question has a group by call. For example we have no idea how $payments is built